How is the dilogarithm defined?
I am pretty happy with the definition of the "maximal analytic contiuation of the logarithm" as
$$
\operatorname{Log}_{\gamma}\left(z\right) =
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{\xi}
\,{\rm d}\xi\quad\mbox{where}\quad\gamma\left(t\right) : \left[0,1\right] \to \mathbb{C}
$$
is a curve in $\mathbb{C}$, not passing through $0$, from $\gamma\left(0\right) = 1$ to $\gamma\left(1\right) = z$.

By counting the number of times the path $\gamma$ crosses the negative real axis, we can relate this definition to the standard definition of the principle branch $\operatorname{Log}\left(z\right)$ by ${\operatorname{Log}_{\gamma_{n}}\left(z\right) = \operatorname{Log}(z) + 2n\pi{\rm i}}$ where $\gamma_{n}$ is a curve from $1$ to $z$ that crosses the negative real axis $n$ times ( counterclockwise ).
Now, Wikipedia defines the dilogarithm as $\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(z\right) = -\int_{0}^{z}{\ln\left(1 - u\right) \over u}\,{\rm d}u $. I have a few questions about this definition.




a) Which branch of the logarithm are they using for $\ln(1-u)$?
b) Does it matter?
2.
a) Why do they not specify an integration contour from $0$ to $z$? Does it not matter?
b) I am surprised that they integrate from $0$, as, at $0$ the integrand is not defined. I guess we can deal with this in terms of a limit not too badly, but the whole reason we started from $1$ before was to avoid this.
3.
Can this dilogarithm be written in terms of just one integral, encompassing both the definition of the dilogarithm and the definition of the logarithm (in terms of an integral)?

We start at $1$ for log because the integral diverges if we start at zero. But $u^{-1}\log(1-u)$ has a removable singularity at zero, so the integral is fine.

@GerryMyerson This makes sense
